# window.opener does not change

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm opening up a popup window using javascript.

The popup windows contains code that when closed will modify some values on the opener window.

something like this...

> window.opener.jQuery('#txtFee').trigger('change');

This logic works well when using only one window. But there is a bug...

There are two windows that have the ability to open up this popup window. If I open the popup from one window and leave the popup open, then I open up the popup from the other window, the popup will get refreshed just fine but the window.opener still references the first window I used to open the popup. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the both windows that open the popup, you can bind `onbeforeunload` and/or `onunload` events to the pop-up window.

```
var popWindow = window.open(url, name, options, replace);
popWindow.focus();

popWindow.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    $('#txtFee').trigger('change'); //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
    console.log("onbeforeunload fired from ", popWindow.name);
}

popWindow.onunload = function()
{
    console.log("onunload fired from ", popWindow.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This looks like a pretty good solution, I just can't seem to get the events to fire when the window gets closed. The popup window gets closed when a 'Save' button is hit and the server side injects some javascript into the popup page to close the window.  

btnSave_Click { ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript("window.opener.$('txtFee').val('somevalue');window.close(););
}

Something like that. Any idea why the events aren't firing from the opener page?

Comment: Tested and it seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/jL56j/ -Some thoughts: 1) it seems your popup aspx registers a startup script. That script might be closing the page before the events are bound by the opener. 2) What is your browser and version? It might be expecting a return value since onbeforeunload accepts a returnValue. Maybe, try `return null;` or `return "";` at the end of the handler. 3) If IE, you can try debugging with Developer Tools; otherwise firebug to see if there are any JS errors. 4) Your ScriptManager might be removing scripts bound previously to the popup in your code?.